# What are good references to understand how Cooper pairs transport charges in superconductors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electric-current, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, non-equilibrium

I am trying to get a deep understanding of superconductors (in the BCS treatment) and I am now focusing on a detailed description of charge flow in superconductors. I have managed to find some partial answers on this forum [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145705/) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177211/) as well as in some textbook such as *Introduction to superconductivity* by Tinkham. I would like to find a reference which presents a detailed description (with calculations and I am not afraid of dealing with hardcore mathematics) of the charge flow in a superconductor subjected to a general electromagnetic field (especially which includes a uniform DC electric field).

In particular, not everything is clear to me yet:

- How is a DC supercurrent generated? Say an electric field is applied by generating a electric potential gradient adiabatically from an instant infinitely far in the past. Can we still understand the superconducting phase in terms of the BCS ground state? What happens to Cooper pairs?
- What is the transient behavior if the electric field is applied instantaneously (if this makes sense) at a given instant?
- I suppose one needs at least a Boltzmann transport approach to calculate this current. Where is such calculation performed?
- From a naive point of view, it would seem that after a uniform DC electric field is applied, because there is no resistance, charges will just accelerate forever. However the generated current generates a magnetic field which will become detrimental to the superconducting phase. How does all of this balance? In concrete cases, is it required to remove the DC electric field to maintain the supercurrent in the superconductor?

I know I can get some answers from the calculation of the complex conductivity and take the limit to zero frequency, but this does not tell me anything about the actual microscopic mechanism. This calculation is performed by Tinkham but only in specific cases (for the Meissner effect or electrodynamics at non zero frequency). There is an out of equilibrium section in Tinkham's book but it does not help me much I think (I haven't read it in details yet).